# dependency-check in Spring3.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection

Spring2.5 had a feature called dependency-check which can be given for a bean tag and default-dependency-check which can be given at the parent level `<beans>` tag.

Eg: `<bean id="soandSo" class="..." dependecy-check=""/>`

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd" 
    default-dependency-check="all">
```

however in Spring3.x these attributes are deprecated, is there any alternate way of setting dependency-check apart from using `@Required` attribute and any equivalent to default-dependency-check in Spring3.x??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is **no loger supported since Spring 3.x**. You can achieve similar result by telling Spring to respect `@Required` and `@Autowired` annotations. It can be done using any of the following configuration options within XML context file:

1. `<context:annotation-config/>`
2. `<context:component-scan base-package="*"/>`

You can skip those options by registering appropriate `BeanPostProcessors` such as `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` and `RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`.

Answer (score 0):

I think no, because In Spring 2.5 annotations were fully embraced and as the framework evolves through these types of changes, its evident that annotations will continue to be a strong driver in keeping the framework as clear and straightforward as possible.

Spring team now encourages developers to use the following alternatives going forward (with Spring 3 and beyond).

- Use constructors (constructor injection instead of setter injection)
  exclusively to ensure the right properties are set. Create setters
  with a dedicated init method implemented.
- Create setters with `@Required` annotation when the property is required.
- Use `@Autowired`-driven injection which also implies a required property by
  default.